# Replace specific string using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this,

```
var str="<svg width='321' height='987'></svg>";
```

I want to replace `width` and `height` of this string using JavaScript(widht and height is dynamic here). 
I tried this

```
str.replace("width='", "width='100%");
```

But i know this will not work. i dont know how to replace text within specific string in javascript. Output should looks like,

```
var str="<div width='100%' height='100%'></div>";
```

Replace should be only for first occurrence within string.

Comment: Can you put some code which you have tried

Comment: str.replace("width='", "width='100%");  @Meena but dont know how to only replace text within `width`

Comment: `str.replace("width='[^']+", "width='100%");`

Answer (score 4):

[Don't try to do regex/string stuff on chunks of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use the browser to parse it:

```js
var str = "<svg width='321' height='987'></svg>";

var tempWrapper = document.createElement("div");
tempWrapper.innerHTML = str;
tempWrapper.firstChild.setAttribute("width", "100");
tempWrapper.firstChild.setAttribute("height", "100")

console.log(tempWrapper.innerHTML);

document.querySelector(".myPage").innerHTML = tempWrapper.innerHTML;
```

```css
svg { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div class="myPage"></div>
```

Comment: but i have no image tag there, i have custom html code which has custom height and width attribute.

Comment: It can be any valid HTML tag that supports those attributes.

Comment: Again, it can be any tag that can be parsed to valid HTML. I've changed the snippet to show how the `str` ends up as a 100 x 100 `<svg>` element.